# Dynamic page growth and smooth, at that?

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, html

I haven't really ever done anything with dynamic pages growing on me so I am wondering what the real trick is. I set up an example and gave it some dynamic content, however getting the page to respond correctly, and smoothly is not going the way I had thought.

Here is what I have currently for my jQuery controller

```
var container = $('#container'),
    heightOrig = $(document).height(),
    contHeightOrig = container.height(),
    limit = 8,
    current = 0;

$('.current').html( heightOrig + 'px' );

var end = setInterval(function() {
    
    if ( current === limit ) {
        if ( contHeightOrig != container.height() ) {
            container.height($(document).height());
        }
        clearInterval( end );
    }
    
    var height = $(document).height(),
        newEnd = $('.offset:last-child'),
        appendNew = '<div class="offset"><p class="adjustment">HTML at ' + height + 'px</p></div>';

    if ( contHeightOrig != container.height() ) {
        container.height($(document).height());
    }
    
    newEnd.after(appendNew);
    
    current++;
    
}, 1000);
```

Obviously the content being displayed is just a simple append for now, as I'm trying to understand the functionality of this.

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/K8vfv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to adjust the page height or container with javascript as long as you don't set fixed heights to those objects. As you add more content, their heights will automatically adjust.

Modified CSS

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body > #container { min-height: 100%; }
#content { padding-bottom: 100px; }
#footer { clear: both; position: relative; z-index: 10; height: 100px; margin-top: 0; }
```

Modified JS

```
var container = $('#container'),
heightOrig = $(document).height(),
contHeightOrig = container.height(),
limit = 8,
current = 0;

$('.current').html( heightOrig + 'px' );

var end = setInterval(function() {

    if ( current === limit ) {
        //if ( contHeightOrig != container.height() ) {
        //    container.height($(document).height()-100);
        //}
        clearInterval( end );
    }

    var height = $(document).height(),
        newEnd = $('.offset:last-child'),
        appendNew = '<div class="offset"><p class="adjustment">HTML at ' + height + 'px</p></div>';

    //if ( contHeightOrig != container.height() ) {
        //container.height($(document).height()-100);
    //}

    newEnd.after(appendNew);

    current++;

    }, 1000);
```

Here is an updated fork for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rvm6L/

EDIT:

OK, here is a jsfiddle with the smooth animation. Took a little finagling, and you're going to want to clean up the CSS and JavaScript. Solution is not different than what I proposed, just added a little animation for you that adjusts based on the difference between the amount of content versus the viewport (jQuery(window).height())

http://jsfiddle.net/Rvm6L/2/

Good luck!

Comment: It sorta breaks the layout a bit, and how about smoothing? Would you need to use `.animate()` to the new size? Also I updated my code and got it to work without the break (the -100 was no longer needed as I removed margining)

Comment: Yes, but what is the point of smoothing? The content is growing at the bottom where it's not visible anyway. I can apply some fixes for the fixed footer if you like, but I'm curious as to what you intend for animation

Comment: That's the thing, it will be visible as the user will be watching the bottom of the page for the new update xD, and the list must remain to refer to.

Comment: I **[did this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wwbn7/)** with animate, but it's not as smooth, or nearly as responsive with the content underlaying before it animates.

Comment: Thing is that no matter what the user is looking at, when something is added to the bottom, nothing changes for their current view. I'll take a look at the last link you just posted, but here is an updated one that at least keeps the footer at the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/Rvm6L/1/

Comment: OK, if you want the footer to slide down then you'll just need to keep it position absolute and you'll need to do an animate that pushes it's "bottom" css property up the amount of the content added and then animates it to 0. lemme see if I can whip something up.

Comment: Whoa, that last comment did not comprehend well... No offense to you, I just don't understand it. I think I understand that with `position:absolute;` it has a `left` and `bottom` attribute set of some sort, or something along those lines. THe math involved though just lost me.

Comment: I just **[tried this](http://jsfiddle.net/LcpQj/)** which did not go over well... I thought it'd run the append after each animation yet it animates a bunch of space at the end of the loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50745/discussion-between-wasasquatch-and-lawrence-johnson)